# How to check if a text file is empty c#

Tags: c#, if-statement

How do I write an if statement to check if my text file is empty?

The if statement below doesn't work for my text file as my file size is not zero even though it is visually empty, because the encoding type of the text file is UTF-8 with BOM so its size is 3 bytes:

```
if (new FileInfo("file").Length == 0)
{
  //Is empty
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to check for a file of length 0 ***or*** a file of length three containing only a UTF-8 BOM:

```
long fileLen = new FileInfo("file").Length;
if (fileLen == 0 || (fileLen == 3 && File.ReadAllBytes("file").SequenceEqual(new byte[] { 239, 187, 191 }))) {
    /* Is empty */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
if (File.ReadAllText(filepath).Length == 0)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Or better if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(File.ReadAllText(filePath))) ...  That will give us a clue what's in the file: I think we know the .Length property isn't zero

Comment: `if (File.ReadLines(filepath).Any(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))) {...}`, please don't read entire (may be huge file) just in order to find out that its `Length` greater than 0

Answer (score -1):

You can check like this your file is empty or not;

```
    string fileName = "file.txt";

    FileInfo info = new FileInfo(fileName);
    if(info.Length ==0){


    }
```

Comment: How is this different than what OP tried? You just broke it into more parts without changing anything meaningful.

Comment: I separated the pieces so that they could be more descriptive. The file extension is missing and I'm just trying to help.

Comment: It sounds like "file" is just an abstraction of OP's real path/filename. Based on the comments, it's getting the info correctly but it's not what OP is expecting.